# KSH script emulating GNU 'ls' command returns only one result when parameter is used

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, ls

I've been trying to utilize this script given to me to highlight directories and other files on an AIX box...

Using:

`/script/location/directory/lsc.sh -la`

works fine. Highlights everything properly, etc.

Using:

`/script/location/directory/lsc.sh -la *specific_parameter*`

returns only the first record that matches with the parameter and none of the others(which there is at least a dozen or so actual matches).

My experience with shell scripting is lacking a bit in comparison to other languages I use. I'm not sure if it's something obvious or not that is causing it to only return the one result and what a possible solution would be to allow proper ls-like functionality.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Below is the script itself:

```
#!/bin/ksh

#***************************************************************************
#***************************************************************************
#* Check to see if any parameters were passed.  If not, just list files.   *
#***************************************************************************
if [[ $1 = ""  || $(echo $1|cut -b1) = "/" ]]
then
   ls $1
   exit 0
fi


#***************************************************************************
#* Issue ls with parameters, send to a tmp file                            *
#* $1 is any ls parameters - ie -la                                        *
#* $2 may be a directory other than CWD - ie /etc                          *
#* the grep -v is in case this is issued in home dir - we dont want to see *
#* our tmp file since it will be deleted when this script finishes.        *
#***************************************************************************
ls $1 $2 | grep -v $$.tmp >> ${HOME}/$$.tmp

#***************************************************************************
#* Process the file.                                                       *
#* If dir: blue, link: light blue, char/block device: inverse blue, white  *
#* socket: red, everything else: no color                                  *
#***************************************************************************
while read LINE
do
  TYPE=$(echo $LINE|cut -b1)
  case $TYPE in
           d) echo "\033[0;91m$LINE\033[0m" ;;
           l) echo "\033[0;92m$LINE\033[0m" ;;
        [cb]) echo "\033[44;37m$LINE\033[0m" ;;
           s) echo "\033[0;31m$LINE\033[0m" ;;
           -) if [[ $(echo $LINE|cut -b4) = "x" || \
                    $(echo $LINE|cut -b7) = "x" || \
                    $(echo $LINE|cut -b10) = "x" ]]
              then
                echo "\033[0;96m$LINE\033[0m"
              else
                echo "\033[0m$LINE"
              fi ;;
           *) echo "\033[0m$LINE" ;;
  esac
done < ${HOME}/$$.tmp

#***************************************************************************
#* Clean up the tmp file                                                   *
#***************************************************************************
rm ${HOME}/$$.tmp
```

Comment: This script is broken. Return it to the vendor and ask your money back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great script, but then you are not using it like it was intented to work IMHO.

```
/script/location/directory/lsc.sh -la
```

$1: -la
$2: nothing

```
/script/location/directory/lsc.sh -la *something*
```

The shell does wildcard expansion like this:

```
/script/location/directory/lsc.sh -la 1something1 2something2 3something3 ...
```

So wildcard expansion happends **before** the script is called.

Therefore, with that last call of lsc.sh:

$1: -la
$2: 1something1

and the script does `ls $1 $2` so only the first directory is processed, which is what you see.

---

If you want it to process all arguments, after wildcard expansion, replace:

```
ls $1 $2 | grep -v $$.tmp >> ${HOME}/$$.tmp
```

by

```
args=$1
shift
ls $args $@ | grep -v $$.tmp >> ${HOME}/$$.tmp
```

---

I found the script here: https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6627

One of the most common link you will see here is "Why *not* parse `ls`" at link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead

The other thing I cannot garantee that this fix will work for all wildcard conditions, so it is provided 'as-is', YMMV.

Comment: Oh, I was late, I just wanted to suggest using `ls -l "$@" | grep -v $$.tmp >>${HOME}/$$.tmp`